# Is "they are by the hill" grammatical?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, exam-questions

Can I write:

> They aren't by the lake, they are by the hill.

My son had task in workbook to continue sentence

> They aren't by the lake, they are by the ....

He wrote in such way

> They aren't by the lake, they are by the hill

but his teacher told him that this sentence don't have meaning. I am not agree with her opinion. But maybe it's not right to use "by" with "hill". I have find answers on tasks on workbook and there was written:

> They aren't by the lake, they are by the pond

What's difference between "hill" and "pond" in this sentence?[image]

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with "they are by the *hill*", although it's a little strange when talking about people.  It's fine with something larger, for example:

> The hospital is located **by the small hill** on the east side of town.

People are usually *on* a hill, otherwise you might say something like:

> They are on the ground **near** the hill

or various other possibilities.  But "by the hill" does make sense.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Honestly I thought "by the hill" is similar "near with hill" and i can use it in such context.

Comment: @НайдановаОльга   Yes, the two prepositions are similar, but not exactly the same.  Sometimes one will sound better than the other.  With people, I would feel it's more important to specify they are either *on* or *not on* the hill, and then perhaps add more information.

Answer (score 2):

> "They aren't by the lake, they are by the hill." ✅

That is a correct English sentence. (notice the placement of the comma)

I don't know what the teacher is complaining about. Maybe the sentence refers to a story in which there is a lake and a pond?

Answer (score 0):

Without any further context about the teacher's objection, she might have been talking about the use of the comma—which is a comma splice.

You have two independent clauses in that sentence:

> They aren't by the lake. 
>   They are by the hill.

Normally, a comma should *not* be used to join the two together without the use of a conjunction. So, you would have this instead:

> They aren't by the lake; they are by the hill.
>   They aren't by the lake. They are by the hill.
>   They aren't by the lake, **but** they are by the hill.

---

Sometimes, comma splices are considered acceptable if the clauses are very short and succinct—or if being used for deliberate stylistic effect. But if the teacher is applying strict traditional grammar conventions, she would consider the sentence to be poorly formed.

---

Note that if she has no problem with *They aren't by the lake, they are by the* ***pond***, then I am at a loss to understand the distinction. (Although you say it was you who found that specific sentence in the workbook, not that she brought it up, so maybe there's an inconsistency between her and the workbook.)

Comment: I added picture from workbook, to show that problem is not in comma. In fact i think child should guess and decide that " pond" is definitly best choice.

Comment: @НайдановаОльга Then I fall back to my last paragraph. It's not clear if the teacher is correctly interpreting the workbook—or perhaps something got lost in communication.